# Using pattern matching to choose between struct fields

Tags: rust

**Background:**

I am trying to implement a simple Virtual Machine in Rust. For now, I am working on a *"RegisterBank"* which supports space for Strings and Integers.
The *RegisterBank* struct looks the following:

```
pub struct RegisterBank {
    int_registers: Vec<i32>,
    str_registers: Vec<String>,
}
```

So it is just a simple collection of two vectors.

**Previous work:**

When I tried to implement the "load" and "store" functions, there was the choice between two seperate functions

```
pub fn load_int(...) { ... }
pub fn load_str(...) { ... }
```

and pattern matching (which I wanted to learn anyway)

```
pub fn load(self, register: SomeMatchableType) {
    match register { ... }
}
```

Because having one function for two very similar tasks seemed good, I tried something like this:

```
enum OperandType {
    Number(i32),
    Word(String),
}
```

and then have a function like `pub fn load(self, register: OperandType)` which matches register and returns either a String (or &str, whatever) or an integer depending on its operand type.

**Problem:**
Currently the implementation is stuck on two seperate functions (for i32 and String) and this is working fine. Since I have managed to do this for `fn store(&mut self, register: usize, value: OperandType)` this should be possible for `fn load(self, register: ???)` as well. My biggest problem is to design such a function that combines both tasks into one pattern match depending on the `OperandType` enum (or maybe something else if someone has a clever idea).

Basically, the solution should do:

1. Decide which register (int_registers or str_register) to choose based on input parameter
2. Get the content of the register
3. Return it

Comment: You could make a `enum RegisterType { Number(usize), Word(usize) }`

Comment: BTW this doesn't really have anything to do with your question but I think your code could look more idiomatic if you renamed `OperandType` to just `Operand`

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible for `load()` to pattern-match on an input parameter because as defined it simply doesn't have one that could be matched. What you seem to really be looking for is a way to make `load()` generic *by return type* — and you are in luck because Rust actually makes that possible.

You need to create a generic trait and provide implementations for the types you are covering, in your case`i32` and `String`:

```
trait LoadFromRegister<T> {
    fn load(&self, register: usize) -> T;
}

impl LoadFromRegister<i32> for RegisterBank {
    fn load(&self, register: usize) -> i32 {
        self.int_registers[register]
    }
}

impl LoadFromRegister<String> for RegisterBank {
    fn load(&self, register: usize) -> String {
        self.str_registers[register].clone()
    }
}
```

`load` can be called either by providing a return type in the context or explicitly using the starfish operator:

```
let intreg: i32 = rb.load(2);  // or, let intreg = rb.load::<i32>(2);
let strreg: String = rb.load(2);
```

Similar technique can be used to get rid of the clunky `OperandType` wrapper. Define a `StoreToRegister` trait that provides `store()` and implement it for `RegisterBank` with `i32` and `String` value types doing the concrete stores:

```
trait StoreToRegister<T> {
    fn store(&mut self, register: usize, value: T);
}

impl StoreToRegister<i32> for RegisterBank {
    fn store(&mut self, register: usize, n: i32) {
        self.int_registers[register] = n;
    }
}

impl StoreToRegister<String> for RegisterBank {
    fn store(&mut self, register: usize, s: String) {
        self.str_registers[register] = s;
    }
}
```

This provides the closest Rust equivalent to argument overloading, allowing `main()` to look like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut rb = RegisterBank::new();
    rb.store(2, 5);
    rb.store(2, "foo".to_owned());
    let intreg: i32 = rb.load(2);
    let strreg: String = rb.load(2);
    assert!(intreg == 5);
    assert!(strreg == "foo");
}
```

The two traits can be merged into a single `RegisterStorage` trait that provides both `load` and `save`. Complete code [at the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6b18417a169304f0e10e2dd0701ad65f&version=stable&backtrace=0).